# When running a DELETE statement, why do I get MySQL warning ER_BINLOG_UNSAFE_WRITE_AUTOINC_SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings, auto-increment, sql-delete

The exact warning I get is:

> Note  | 1592 | Unsafe statement written to the binary log using
>   statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing
>   to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another
>   table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved
>   determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be
>   predicted and may differ on master and the slave.

This warning seems to make sense... what doesn't make sense is that I get it when running a DELETE statement, ie, something like:

```
# Let's get extinct!
DELETE FROM dinosaurs
USING dinosaurs, eras
WHERE dinosaurs.id_era = eras.ida_era AND
    eras.era_name = "cretaceous"
```

Why would order from the select matter when I'm REMOVING rows??

None of the tables involved have any triggers... could this just be a MySQL bug? My version is: 5.5.28-29.1-log

Comment: Don't know why it would be with removing rows (no triggers?), but I switched to `BINLOG_FORMAT=MIXED` to make sure actual problems don't occur.

Comment: (added a note about there not being any triggers...)

Comment: Hm, it may just be that it _can_ matter, not that it _does_ matter here. It all depends on how 'smart' the check is.